# Create link on page w/ web address stored in database

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, href

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't seem to figure it out.  All of my google searches lead me to linking to databases which isn't what I want to do.  I'm a complete web development newb.

I've roughly followed the NerdDinner tutorial in creating my web app.  One of my stored fields is a web address.  On the Index and Details pages, when I display the info from my record, I want the web address to be a clickable link to the website.

It's currently displayed as:

```
<%= Html.Encode(Model.Subcontract.company1.website) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="<%= Html.Encode(Model.Subcontract.company1.website) %>"><%= Html.Encode(Model.Subcontract.company1.website) %></a>
```

or

```
<a href="<%= Html.Encode(Model.Subcontract.company1.website) %>">Company website</a>
```

If you use DataAnnotations, you can read about `DataTypeAttribute`. If you decorate property with this property with `EmailAddress` data type and use `DisplayFor` helper, you'll get similar effect.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know you could embed the Html.Encode within the href.  I have some email addresses that I will probably want to do at a later date, so now I know what to read up on.

Comment: When I click the link, it brings me to http://mysite/Subcontracts/Details/www.stackoverflow.com rather than www.stackoverflow.com  How, do I tell it that it's not an internal link?

`<a href="<%= Html.Encode(item.company1.website) %>" target="_blank"><%= Html.Encode(item.company1.website) %></a>`

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to make the information returned by Model.Subcontract.company1.website clickable?  If so you can just write that information into an anchor tag like so:

```
<a href="<%= Html.Encode(Model.Subcontract.company1.website) %>"><%= Html.Encode(Model.Subcontract.company1.website) %></a>
```

Otherwise you can do it on the PageLoad event by using an

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="mylink" runat="server" />
```

and placing the following in the PageLoad event of the code behind:

```
mylink.NavigateUrl = Model.Subcontract.company1.website
mylink.Text = Model.Subcontract.company1.website
```

Comment: That is MVC, we don't have PageLoad event here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two extension methods for the HTML helper class that generates a link:

```
public static MvcHtmlString HtmlLink(this HtmlHelper html, string url, string text)
{
    return HtmlLink(html, url, text, null);
}

public static MvcHtmlString HtmlLink(this HtmlHelper html, string url, string text, object htmlAttributes)
{
    TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("a");
    tb.InnerHtml = text;
    tb.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    tb.MergeAttribute("href", url);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

Then you can just do this:

```
<%= Html.HtmlLink(Model.Subcontract.company1.website, Model.Subcontract.company1.website) %>
```